# Python itertools: Best way to unpack product of product of list of lists

Tags: python, python-itertools, flatten, iterable-unpacking

I have a list of lists over which I need to iterate 3 times (3 nested loops)

```
rangeList = [[-0.18,0.18],[0.14,0.52],[0.48,0.85]]
```

I can achieve this using product of product as follows

```
from itertools import product
for val in product(product(rangeList,rangeList),rangeList):
    print val
```

The output looks as follows

```
(([-0.18, 0.18], [-0.18, 0.18]), [-0.18, 0.18])
(([-0.18, 0.18], [-0.18, 0.18]), [0.14, 0.52])
(([-0.18, 0.18], [-0.18, 0.18]), [0.48, 0.85])
(([-0.18, 0.18], [0.14, 0.52]), [-0.18, 0.18])
```

Its a tuple of tuple. My questions are

1. Is this a good approach?
2. If so, what is the bestway to unpack the
   output of the product `val` into 3 separate variables say `xRange`, `yRange` and
   `zRange`, where each holds a list value of say `[-0.18, 0.18]` or `[0.14, 0.52]` etc.

Comment: Look into the `repeat` argument to `itertools.product`. You want `product(rangeList, repeat=3)`. Though `product(rangeList, rangeList, rangeList)` also works.

Comment: `val` is not an iterator, but the result of `product` is. By the way, what you want your `xRange`, `yRange` and `zRange` look like? What values should they contain?

Comment: it is possible you want `product(*rangeList)` to get desired result but I can't know unless you show the desired output/values for `xRange` / `yRange` / `zRange`

Comment: @MarkDickinson the `repeat` option worked beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your desired result? It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably the most elegant way to do what you want:

```
for xrange, yrange, zrange in product(rangeList, repeat=3):
    print xrange, yrange, zrange
```

But just to demonstrate how you can do the "deep" tuple unpacking you were trying:

```
for (xrange, yrange), zrange in product(product(rangeList,rangeList),rangeList):
    print xrange, yrange, zrange
```

Comment: Worked beautifully with the repeat option. Thank you